Why does this for loop never return true?
I have a VueJS computed function that I want to use to control whether or not something shows up on a page. I'm having trouble with it, I expect it to end iterating on return but it continues going and never sustains return true
HTML element on vue page:
<div v-if="infoExists">Some Stuff Here</div>

I have a function infoExists that:

loops through all of a certain set of objects within a parent object
checks if some information within the object exists (eventually it should test if it === a certain value, but I have issues even with it just existing, so I'm trying to solve that first)

Expected functionality:

returns true if any one item in object has item.info
stops iterating the for loop if a single item with item.info is found, and simply returns true for the duration of the page load

Actual unwanted behavior:

Iterates through all items in the set correctly
Finds when an item has item.info correctly
Continues to iterate throughout the rest of the items
Never returns as true even if every item in object has item.info
If I set return false at the end outside of the loop, it always returns as false

    infoExists() {
      console.log('infoExists') // always prints correctly

      Object.values(this.set.items).forEach( (item) => {
        console.log(item) // logs correct item, keeps printing items even after an item containing item.info is passed previously
        if (item.info) {
          console.log('has info') // correctly logs when has info
          return true; // expect for the loop to break here and for the function to return true
        }
      } );

       // return false; // if this is uncommented, it always returns false
    },

How do I get this to simply:

Check if any item has item.info
If it does, return true
If no item has item.info return false


The array method .forEach never breaks early, and the return value of the inner function has no effect. Did you mean to do for (const item of Object.values(this.set.items)) { instead?

AHA!!! Yes this fixed my issue, thanks so much!

The appropriate method here is Array#some.

The some() method of Array instances tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

return Object.values(this.set.items).some(item => item.info);

